# how to get result from URL upto port number using postgres function regexp_replace?

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-group

I need your help to get substring from a given string using `regexp_replce` function of Postgres DB.

I am trying a following query,

```
select regexp_replace('http://localhost:8080/redirectHome?abc=xyz&sortBy=111', '(.*?/){3}', '');
```

But it gives me wrong a result or unexpected one.

Expected result is: `http://localhost:8080`

My doubt is, I am providing wrong input either in `regex` place or something else into `regex_replace` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match 3 sequences of `/` separated chunks from the start of the string, capture that part, and then just match the rest of the string to remove it:

```
select regexp_replace('http://localhost:8080/redirectHome?abc=xyz&sortBy=111', '^([^/]*(?:/[^/]*){2}).*', '\1');
```

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `([^/]*(?:/[^/]*){2})` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1` placeholder from the replacement pattern):

  - `[^/]*` - any 0+ chars other than `/`
  - `(?:/[^/]*){2}` - 2 consecutive occurrences of:

    - `/` - a slash
    - `[^/]*` - any 0+ chars other than `/`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `\1` - a placeholder that inserts the captured text in Group 1 back into the resulting string.

Or, extract text before the 4th `/`:

```
select regexp_matches('http://localhost:8080/redirectHome?abc=xyz&sortBy=111', '^[^/]*(?:/[^/]*){2}');
```

Here, `^[^/]*(?:/[^/]*){2}` matches the first 0+ chars other than `/` and then matches 2 occurrences of `/` followed with another 0+ chars other than `/`.

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/NGQ96117):

[image]

Comment: in my case, port can be vary in any digit(2, 3, 4..) & I must need an answer using regexp_replace function only. could you please re-try & let me know the solution if you could.

Comment: @vishalgajera I was out for a walk: sitting all day in front of the screen is killing... You may replace `{4}` with `+` to match 1 or more digits.

Comment: Actually, you may use almost identical patterns in both `matches` and `replace` functions, see  my answer update.

Answer (score 0):

I see the detailed answer above, but here is something a different answer. It took only 9 steps

```
/^([^\d]*)([\d]*)/
```

the first capture groups captures everything from very beginning to right before the port number

and the second capturing group captures the port number

https://regex101.com/r/h9xHl3/1/